# how to calculate the number of a table's rows changed(update or insert) in a day on mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a trade records table and i want to calculate the rows of this table changed including update or insert.
I have check the information_schema in mysql.There is a table called TABLE and it has a column TABLE_ROWS.But i didn't find anything helpful.

well,this table like this

```
CREATE TABLE pre_actived_apk_record
(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    appid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    channelid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    uid INT(11) NOT NULL,
    appname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    packagename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    versioncode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    versionname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    brand VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    imei VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    sys_version VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    mac_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    imsi VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    iccid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    uploadtime INT(11) NOT NULL,
    dateline INT(11) NOT NULL,
    rule INT(11) NOT NULL,
    price INT(11) NOT NULL
);
```

And i wonder i could use some built-in method to show the result of this table chanaged.

Comment: Can you show us table structure?

Comment: Can you alter your table? Add a new column?